# pdfpages package and layoutsize (geometry package)

Tags: paper-size, geometry, pdfpages

I tried to include a PDF page using the `pdfpages` package — this works well for a standard case, f.e. (`t.pdf` is the first page of the [PGF manual](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={155mm,220mm}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includepdf{t.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Output of the first MWE].

In my case, my printer needs an additional trimming edge, since I use full-page images. For all other publications (there was no need to include other PDF files) I used the very comfortable option `layoutsize` in combination with `papersize` of the `geometry` package. Unfortunately, if I use this option, the `pdfpages` package does ignore it (exaggerated by intention):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={200mm,300mm}, layoutsize={155mm,220mm}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includepdf{t.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Output of the second MWE]

As you can see, the layout of the text content is untouched, but the included PDF is scaled to the paper size, not to the layout size. Is there a possibility to include a PDF file while respecting the layout size given by the `geometry` package?

Thank you for your help in advance.

**Edit:**
I have forgotten to take the `layoutoffset` option of the `geometry` package into account in my question. A solution should not only respect the given layout size, but also its offset specification.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={200mm,300mm}, layoutsize={155mm,220mm}, layoutoffset={10mm,5mm}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includepdf{t.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you edit also the example code to show your real options to `geometry`?

Comment: @egreg: Because my screenshots would not suit any longer. Because of this circumstance, I added a code example at the end of my question, but I think that's only a trivial addendum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the layout width and height (of course you can use the figures you know, but this is independent from them):

```
\makeatletter
\includepdf[
  pages=1,
  width=\Gm@layoutwidth,
  height=\Gm@layoutheight,
  offset={\dimexpr(\Gm@layoutwidth-\paperwidth)/2\relax}
         {\dimexpr(\paperheight-\Gm@layoutheight)/2\relax},
  keepaspectratio
  ]{pgfmanual.pdf}
\makeatother
```

Of course it won't be perfect unless the proportions of the layout dimension are the same as that of the PDF you're including.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; that's the solution I'm searching for. I supposed that it would be necessary to get the `geometry`-specified parameters, but I had no idea how to do that. In order to take the `layoutoffset` option additionally into account (I realized that after your answer), I changed `{\dimexpr(\Gm@layoutwidth-\paperwidth)/2\relax}` to `{\dimexpr(\Gm@layoutwidth-\paperwidth)/2+\Gm@layouthoffset\relax}` and `{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\Gm@layoutheight)/2\relax}` to `{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\Gm@layoutheight)/2-\Gm@layoutvoffset\relax}`. Thank you really much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

The [pdfpages manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) says

> Internally the command `\includepdf` makes use of the `\includegraphics`
>   command from the `graphicx` (actually graphics) package. Hence it is
>   possible to use all the options of `\includegraphics`, too. Options
>   which are not interpreted by `\includepdf` are passed directly to
>   `\includegraphics`.

Hence, you can set the width and height directly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={200mm,300mm}, layoutsize={155mm,220mm}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includepdf[width=155mm,height=220mm]{pgfmanual.pdf}
\end{document}
```

You might want to look at the `offset` option, which changes the position of the inserted pdf page.

The [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) stores the page dimensions using macros that start with `\Gm@`, so `layoutheight` is stored in `\Gm@layoutheight`, etc. The easiest way to use these is probably to create a custom macro.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myincludepdf[1]{\includepdf[width=\Gm@layoutwidth,height\Gm@layoutheight{#1}}
\makeatother
```

...

```
\myincludepdf{pgfmanual.pdf}
```

If you want to position the included page differently, you could do something similar with the layout offsets from `geometry` and the `offset` option for `\includepdf`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm aware of the `graphicx` options for `\includepdf`. Unfortunately, you describe only a manual (partial) solution for this issue, but is there a way to automate `\includepdf` just to respect the options of `geometry` (f.e. `layoutoffset`)? I can't imagine that this use case is so unusual. Your MWE gives an embedding of the first page of the PGF manual, which is centered on the page (strictly speaking, this is not an answer to my question).

Comment: I have edited my answer. You might want to edit your question as well, because it does not mention offsets.

Comment: Thank you for your addendum, now the scaling is automated, but not the proper positioning (top left corner). Apart from that I've forgotten to take the `layoutoffset` into account in my question; I will change that.